# Injector error with Angularjs when trying to implement a notifications bar via if-else statements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get the following error - angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope

I am trying to send a subscribe message, using pubnub, and incorporate an ng-notifications-bar for whether the subscribe message comes through successfully or not.

The code is as follows for the controller, the main parts which I am not sure about is the ngNotifications part, (showError, showSuccess, showWarning etc). You will see in the last part I've implemented an if else statement to specify when to apply a success notification and when to apply an error notification:

myApp.controller('NotificationsController',['$scope','$http','$rootScope','$location','token_service','PubNub','notifications', function($scope,$http,$rootScope,$location,token_service,PubNub,notifications){

```
  $scope.noti = [];
  function theCallback (x){
    $scope.$apply(function () {
      $rootScope.spinner = false;
      $scope.noti = x[0];
      console.log(x[0]);
    });
  }

  $scope.showError = function () {
    notifications.showError("Error, are you sure you've followed the correct process?");
  };
  $scope.showWarning = function () {
    notifications.showWarning('Having trouble, please try again.');
  };
  $scope.showSuccess = function () {
    notifications.showSuccess('Welcome to Chui!');
  };

  $rootScope.defaultInstance.history({channel:"chui_channel", count:100,callback:theCallback});

  $rootScope.spinner = true;
  $scope.keys='test_notifications'
}])
//myApp.controller('SignoutController',['$scope','$rootScope','$location','token_service','signout_service','$window',function($scope,$rootScope,$location,token_service,signout_service,$window){

myApp.run(function($scope,$rootScope,$location,$templateCache,$window,$cookies,$route,api_service,notifications) {

    $rootScope.defaultInstance = PUBNUB.init({
        publish_key: 'pub-c-5aace072-1c95-4d6c-8b95-28638c4bd6a2',
        subscribe_key: 'sub-c-0ac5d634-10aa-11e6-bbd9-02ee2ddab7fe'
    });



    var device = api_service.get_devices()
    device.then(function(response){
      $rootScope.devices = response;
      console.log(response);
      var deviceSerialList = new String
      for (var d in response){
        deviceSerialList = String(response[d].DeviceId) +',';
        var l = deviceSerialList.split(',').filter(Boolean);
        if (l.length == response.length){
          listen(deviceSerialList);
          console.log(deviceSerialList);
          $scope.showSuccess = function () {
             notifications.showSuccess('Welcome to Chui!');
         };
        }
        else{
          $scope.showError = function () {
            notifications.showError("Error, are you sure you've followed the correct process?");
          };
        }
      };
    });

    function listen(deviceList){
      $rootScope.defaultInstance.subscribe({
              channel : deviceList,
              message : function (message, envelope, channelOrGroup, time, channel) {
                alert(message)
                  console.log(
                      "Message Received." + "\n" +
                      "Channel or Group : " + JSON.stringify(channelOrGroup) + "\n" +
                      "Channel : " + JSON.stringify(channel) + "\n" +
                      "Message : " + JSON.stringify(message) + "\n" +
                      "Time : " + time + "\n" +
                      "Raw Envelope : " + JSON.stringify(envelope)
                  )
              },
      });
    };
```

In the html page I have included the following:  and it already has

Comment: Hi Will. Welcome to StackOverflow! I recommend changing the title of your question to a description of your problem, not the error you're encountering. Also, if you have some additional information, you better edit your answer than add a comment.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info...much appreciated! Will do so...

Answer (score 0):

`myApp.run(function($scope` - this is the cause. `.run` doesn't take a `$scope` injection - remove it.

Comment: When I remove it the console tells me there is a reference error: $scope is not defined
    at main.js?v=1020:236
    at angular.js:15961
    at n.$eval (angular.js:17229)
    at n.$digest (angular.js:17045)
    at n.$apply (angular.js:17337)
    at l (angular.js:11572)
    at H (angular.js:11778)
    at XMLHttpRequest.u.onload (angular.js:11711)                                                      Any ideas?

Comment: @WillBodansky -- You reference `$scope` inside that function - remove that as well

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. I replaced $scope with $rootScope within the function and it's fixed the error arriving to the console. I'm still not getting the desired functionality, and so I will investigate and try and find the solution. If I'm still at a loss I might come back here for more help :)